# Activity call interface in multiple fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity with a viewpager, the viewpager hosts 3 fragments

`1. A barcode scanner camera fragment, 
2. A map fragment 
3. and a recyclerview fragment`

When the application launches I navigate to fragment 2 (the map fragment) but like we know the `ViewPager` loads more than 1 fragment at a time for a smoother transition because of this the `Barcode scanner on fragment 1` is also initialized and runs in the background, my solution to this was to make an `interface` in my activity like:

```
public class ControllerActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private PageNumberListener pageNumberListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_controller);
      ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      BarcodeScannerFragment barcodeScannerFragment = new BarcodeScannerFragment();
      pageNumberListener = barcodeScannerFragment;
      adapter.addFragment(barcodeScannerFragment);

      viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            pageNumberListener.onCurrentPageChanged(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    }

    public interface PageNumberListener {
      void onCurrentPageChanged(int pageNumber);
    }
}
```

And implemented it in my BarcodeFragment like

```
  public class BarcodeScannerFragment extends Fragment implements ControllerActivity.PageNumberListener {


    @Override
    public void onCurrentPageChanged(int pageNumber) {


    }


  }
```

And start/stop scanning in the `onCurrentPageChanged(in pageNumber)`

My problem now is I need to implement this interface in all my other fragments and when the activity calls the `onCurrentPageChanged(in pageNumber)` I want all the 3 fragments to receive the signal and each do what it is suppose to do, for example when the user scrolls from the `BarcodeScannerFragment` to the `MapFragment` I want the method to be fired to that the `BarcodeScannerFragment` can stop scanning and the `MapFragment` resume location updates, the same goes for the `RecyclerViewFragment`, when the user scrolls from the `MapFragment` to the `RecyclerViewFragment` I want the `MapFragment` to stop location updates and the `RecyclerViewFragment` to pull data in the list. One would say I use the `onResume()` but I feel its not working accordingly. Anyone know how I can make this possible? I tried creating a `BaseFragment` like

```
  public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements ControllerActivity.PageNumberListener  {


      @Override
      public void onCurrentPageChanged(int pageNumber) {

      }
  }
```

And each fragment extend it like

```
 public class MapFragment extends BaseFragment  {
          @Override
          public void onCurrentPageChanged(int pageNumber) {
            super.onCurrentPageChanged(pageNumber)
          }
}

public class BarCodeScannerFragment extends BaseFragment  {
          @Override
          public void onCurrentPageChanged(int pageNumber) {
            super.onCurrentPageChanged(pageNumber)
          }
}


public class RecyclerViewFragment extends BaseFragment  {
          @Override
          public void onCurrentPageChanged(int pageNumber) {
            super.onCurrentPageChanged(pageNumber)
          }
}
```

And in my Activity

```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            pageNumberListener = (PageNumberListener) adapter.getItem(position);
            pageNumberListener.onCurrentPageChanged(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

This works but very shallow, it only fires for the current fragment, I do not know how one call can fire the `onCurrentPageChanged(position)` in all fragments

Comment: It looks like you need eventbus like ie GreenRobot's: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

With Marcin's comment I was successful, I registered the `EventBus` in my `BaseFragment` and `Override` the `onPageChanged(Integer currentPage)` in my `Fragments` accordingly

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment  {


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onPageChanged(Integer currentPage) {

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

}

then in my activity all I had to do is fire the `EventBus` every time the page was changed like

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

And my problem was solved! :)